# MongoDB Slow query by ID

Tags: performance, mongodb, mongodb-java, spring-data-mongodb

I recently migrated my MongoDB database from Windows Server to CentOS.
The version is 2.4.9.
I noticed that I have a slow retrieval of records by _id field!
I ran a repair database over the weekend bu that did not solve the problem.
I have this method that retrieves records by their IDs (with IN operator) (using spring data mongodb 1.4.1.RELEASE):

```java
@Override
public Map<String, Record> findAsMapIds(
    final String[] ids,
    final ComponentType... comps
) {
    if( null == ids || 0 == ids.length ) {
        return null;
    }
    Map<String,Record> result = new HashMap<String,Record>();
    final Criteria cr =  where("_id").in( idArrFunction.apply(ids) );
    final Query qry = new Query( cr );
    setFieldsToReturn( qry, comps );
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    List<Record> ritems = getTemplate().find(qry, Record.class);
    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println( "findAsMapIds()::" + (end-start) );
    for( Record r: ritems ) {
        result.put( r.getId(), r );
    }
    return result;
}

public MongoOperations getTemplate() {
    return template;
}
```

The function idArrFunction returns an array of ObjectId[]

You notice that I'm timing only the data retrieval call.
Also I'm not passing more that 10 ids at a time.
Here is the timing output that I'm getting in the logs when I call this method several times:

```
findAsMapIds()::2092
findAsMapIds()::6666
findAsMapIds()::10007
findAsMapIds()::15132
findAsMapIds()::18341
findAsMapIds()::24709
findAsMapIds()::28731
findAsMapIds()::33888
findAsMapIds()::36862
findAsMapIds()::40206
```

You notice that the time grows with each call I made to this method.

Here are the collection stats:

```js
> db.record.stats();
{
    "ns" : "mydb.record",
    "count" : 1491427,
    "size" : 18292198304,
    "avgObjSize" : 12264.896843090544,
    "storageSize" : 18899890096,
    "numExtents" : 30,
    "nindexes" : 13,
    "lastExtentSize" : 2146426864,
    "paddingFactor" : 1,
    "systemFlags" : 1,
    "userFlags" : 0,
    "totalIndexSize" : 734401024,
    "indexSizes" : {
        "_id_" : 43561728,
        "orgId" : 63192304,
        "type" : 51018240,
        "orgHierarchy" : 63274064,
        "orgHierarchy_mrn" : 75603472,
        "dos" : 25525472,
        "org_pdt" : 77189616,
        "orgHierarchy_processedDtTm" : 77287728,
        "processedDtTm_-1" : 37536016,
        "orgId_states" : 68367712,
        "states" : 27553120,
        "states_1_processedDtTm_-1" : 41624016,
        "orgId_1_states_1_processedDtTm_-1" : 82667536
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

If I printout the Query object from java I get this:

```
Query: { "_id" : { "$in" : [ { "$oid" : "51cbe96dcb81c43374ca9516"} , { "$oid" : "51cbe892cb81c43374ca5e48"} , { "$oid" : "51cbe910cb81c43374ca7aba"} , { "$oid" : "51c00739cb81e6b83ad29d14"} , { "$oid" : "51c06ff4cb81e6b83ad4f69a"} , { "$oid" : "51c07010cb81e6b83ad4f74e"} , { "$oid" : "51c06da5cb81e6b83ad4e775"} , { "$oid" : "51c081bbcb81e6b83ad56437"} , { "$oid" : "51c07fe2cb81e6b83ad557d2"} , { "$oid" : "51c081bbcb81e6b83ad56433"}]}}, Fields: { "text" : 1 , "type" : 1 , "header" : 1 , "orgId" : 1 , "vitals" : 1 , "_id" : 1 , "processedDtTm" : 1 , "orgHierarchy" : 1 }, Sort: null
```

Also if I run explain:

```
> db.record.find({ "_id" : { "$in" : [ ObjectId("51ba0b43cb81e6b83acd9e6b") , ObjectId("51a8feb5cb8168350e373428") , ObjectId("51a90053cb8168350e373948") , ObjectId("51a901fecb8168350e373e82") , ObjectId("51a8f3e9cb8168350e3711d1") , ObjectId("51a8f3eacb8168350e3711d2") , ObjectId("51a8ff3ecb8168350e3735df") , ObjectId("51a8f59ecb8168350e37172b") , ObjectId("51a8f9aacb8168350e372418") , ObjectId("51a8f786cb8168350e371d42")]}}).explain();
{
    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor _id_ multi",
    "isMultiKey" : false,
    "n" : 10,
    "nscannedObjects" : 10,
    "nscanned" : 18,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 10,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 18,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "nYields" : 0,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 0,
    "indexBounds" : {
        "_id" : [
            [
                ObjectId("51a8f3e9cb8168350e3711d1"),
                ObjectId("51a8f3e9cb8168350e3711d1")
            ],
            [
                ObjectId("51a8f3eacb8168350e3711d2"),
                ObjectId("51a8f3eacb8168350e3711d2")
            ],
            [
                ObjectId("51a8f59ecb8168350e37172b"),
                ObjectId("51a8f59ecb8168350e37172b")
            ],
            [
                ObjectId("51a8f786cb8168350e371d42"),
                ObjectId("51a8f786cb8168350e371d42")
            ],
            [
                ObjectId("51a8f9aacb8168350e372418"),
                ObjectId("51a8f9aacb8168350e372418")
            ],
            [
                ObjectId("51a8feb5cb8168350e373428"),
                ObjectId("51a8feb5cb8168350e373428")
            ],
            [
                ObjectId("51a8ff3ecb8168350e3735df"),
                ObjectId("51a8ff3ecb8168350e3735df")
            ],
            [
                ObjectId("51a90053cb8168350e373948"),
                ObjectId("51a90053cb8168350e373948")
            ],
            [
                ObjectId("51a901fecb8168350e373e82"),
                ObjectId("51a901fecb8168350e373e82")
            ],
            [
                ObjectId("51ba0b43cb81e6b83acd9e6b"),
                ObjectId("51ba0b43cb81e6b83acd9e6b")
            ]
        ]
    },
    "server" : "ip-10-0-0-41:27017"
}
```

I turned on the profiler and this is what I get:

```
{
   "op":"query",
   "ns":"sytrue.record",
   "query":{
      "_id":{
     "$in":[
        ObjectId("51b1c98dcb81e4c1566b7436"),
        ObjectId("51b1cb3ccb81e4c1566b79ab"),
        ObjectId("51b1d741cb81e4c1566ba219"),
        ObjectId("51b1caa8cb81e4c1566b77d4"),
        ObjectId("51b1c98ccb81e4c1566b7433"),
        ObjectId("51b1c691cb81e4c1566b6a8c"),
        ObjectId("51b1cc21cb81e4c1566b7c9f"),
        ObjectId("51b1c390cb81e4c1566b60c9"),
        ObjectId("51b1d578cb81e4c1566b9c1d"),
        ObjectId("51b1e13dcb81e4c1566bc30e")
     ]
      }
   },
   "ntoreturn":0,
   "ntoskip":0,
   "nscanned":19,
   "keyUpdates":0,
   "numYield":0,
   "lockStats":{
      "timeLockedMicros":{
     "r":NumberLong(380),
     "w":NumberLong(0)
      },
      "timeAcquiringMicros":{
     "r":NumberLong(2),
     "w":NumberLong(4)
      }
   },
   "nreturned":10,
   "responseLength":36745,
   "millis":0,
   "ts":   ISODate("2014-03-24T09:55:20.988   Z"),
   "client":"127.0.0.1",
   "allUsers":[
      {
     "user":"sytrue-user",
     "userSource":"sytrue"
      }
   ],
   "user":"sytrue-user@sytrue"
}
```

- I also notice that when I retrieve individual record by its ID it is
  also slow (findOne method of PagingAndSortingRepository).
- I have to mention that I did not have this problem on the windows server.
- Please someone explain what's going on.

Update: I noticed that while the results are returned the CPU is consumed by the java code and not mongo server process. So the problem is either in the mongodb-java driver or spring-data-mongodb

Comment: Is the hardware otherwise the same?

Comment: It is way supperior of what It was: It's an amazon EC2 m3.xlarge instance: 4 Cores 15GB and dedicated IOPS

Comment: might be stating the obvious, but have you tried (1) running a sample query from the shell with 'explain'  (2) printing out the actual query - is there a chance your 'in' clause is bigger than it should be?

Comment: Use the integrated mongodb profiler (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/manage-the-database-profiler/) and `explain` to find out what is really happening. Without the output from those tools, it will be hard to find out what's happening here. In particular, it's important to ensure whether the time is spent in MongoDB, or in your application code.

Comment: It cannot be in my app because whats beyond getTemplate().find() call it is not my code. It is spring-data-mongodb, mongodb-driver and mongodb server

Comment: Ok, I meant 'the client code', not 'your code'. Anyway, the `explain` output says it takes 0ms, so the query is not the problem, it must be something else.  What does `getTemplate()` do and how fast is it? Try to isolate the database call so what you measure is really just the DB call, nothing else. Are the objects so large that their deserialization might be the culprit? Are there any first-chance-exceptions that are being handled while the code runs?

Comment: I updated with everything it was asked.

Answer (score 4):

Found the problem chatting with a MongoDB developer:
I was running spring framework 4.0.0 and the slowness is related to this issue:

https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-11335

Updating Spring to version 4.0.1 (or above) solves the problem.

This was the stack trace from my call to the problem:

```
    at java.lang.Class.getGenericSignature(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.getGenericInterfaces(Class.java:813)
    at org.springframework.core.SerializableTypeWrapper$2.getType(SerializableTypeWrapper.java:106)
    at org.springframework.core.SerializableTypeWrapper$TypeProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(SerializableTypeWrapper.java:220)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy5.equals(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.util.ObjectUtils.nullSafeEquals(ObjectUtils.java:252)
    at org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.equals(ResolvableType.java:682)
    at org.springframework.util.ObjectUtils.nullSafeEquals(ObjectUtils.java:252)
    at org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.variableResolverSourceEquals(ResolvableType.java:719)
    at org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.equals(ResolvableType.java:683)
    at org.springframework.util.ConcurrentReferenceHashMap$Segment.findInChain(ConcurrentReferenceHashMap.java:571)
    at org.springframework.util.ConcurrentReferenceHashMap$Segment.getReference(ConcurrentReferenceHashMap.java:439)
    at org.springframework.util.ConcurrentReferenceHashMap.getReference(ConcurrentReferenceHashMap.java:238)
    at org.springframework.util.ConcurrentReferenceHashMap.get(ConcurrentReferenceHashMap.java:217)
    at org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.forType(ResolvableType.java:1018)
    at org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.forType(ResolvableType.java:998)
    at org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.getGenerics(ResolvableType.java:489)
    at org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.getGeneric(ResolvableType.java:451)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.TypeDescriptor.getElementTypeDescriptor(TypeDescriptor.java:305)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.TypeDescriptor.equals(TypeDescriptor.java:456)
    at org.springframework.util.ObjectUtils.nullSafeEquals(ObjectUtils.java:252)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService$ConverterCacheKey.equals(GenericConversionService.java:436)
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.get(ConcurrentHashMap.java:996)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.getConverter(GenericConversionService.java:235)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:176)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:162)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.getPotentiallyConvertedSimpleRead(MappingMongoConverter.java:715)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.readCollectionOrArray(MappingMongoConverter.java:773)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.readValue(MappingMongoConverter.java:1048)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.access$100(MappingMongoConverter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$MongoDbPropertyValueProvider.getPropertyValue(MappingMongoConverter.java:999)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.getValueInternal(MappingMongoConverter.java:755)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$1.doWithPersistentProperty(MappingMongoConverter.java:256)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$1.doWithPersistentProperty(MappingMongoConverter.java:249)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.doWithProperties(BasicPersistentEntity.java:261)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:249)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:223)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:187)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:183)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate$ReadDbObjectCallback.doWith(MongoTemplate.java:1966)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.executeFindMultiInternal(MongoTemplate.java:1662)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doFind(MongoTemplate.java:1487)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doFind(MongoTemplate.java:1471)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.find(MongoTemplate.java:527)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.find(MongoTemplate.java:518)
    at com.sytrue.record.persistence.repo.impl.RecordRepositoryImpl.findAsMapIds(RecordRepositoryImpl.java:139)
```

Comment: I had the same problem. Updating the Spring version to 4.0.3 solved it.

Comment: My problem was slightly different in that I was doing a query for all records in a collection, but this fixed it for me too. Thank you very much! It was starting to look like a right pain!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I have updated my spring framework from 4.0.0 to 4.0.3 and it worked !!!

Comment: respectfully disagree @MeeneshJain

Comment: @MeeneshJain: This is indeed an answer to the question.