# Upload an image parse.com

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I am trying to upload an imagen but when i save the information I can saw the image.Can you help me?

```
            <!-- file-->
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="">Foto</label>
          <div class="col-md-8">
            <input id="imagen" name="imagen" class="form-control input-md" type="file">
         </div>
        </div>
```

I have this input and

```
var bytes = [ 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xCA, 0xFE ];
var url = req.body.imagen;
var file = new Parse.File(url, bytes);
file.save().then(function() {
          alert("Save");
        }, function(error) {
          alert("Fail");
        });
```

I use the javascript guide but i dont know what i miss

Answer (score 1):

You should try with `var url = req.body.imagen.path;` or `var url = req.files.imagen.path;`.

You forgot `.path` for your `url` variable. `imagen` is an object containing various informations about the uploaded file (path for tmp folder, name, size...).

Comment: Can you improve on this answer as it is under scrutiny for shortness. Thanks

Comment: @Drew: Are you new to review? Short answers, if they answer the question, are perfectly fine (and even encouraged!)

Comment: Not new here at all. @gladsocc , exactly. As I comment on *This or That*, other's that say this is not an answer, when it really is (but short). This answer has some wiggle room for improvement. And it is in the queue

Comment: Like [This One](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33991412) @gladsocc ... that is my upvote. Helpin' the little guy

Comment: @Drew I added a little explanation but I don't know what else to say, OP made a simple mistake.

Comment: it wasn't you Shan, I was in one of those moods, other people dumping on short answers, none of them were here, and thought you could sprinkle a few more words. Thx :P

Comment: When I use `var url = req.files.imagen.path;` it mark an Internal Server error and when I use `var url = req.body.imagen.path;` the url is undefined.